# Is my claim that this number is irrational correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, irrational-numbers, infinite-product, transcendental-numbers

Define a number $c$ in the following way: $$c=\ln \left(\prod^\infty_{k=1}\frac{e^{1/k}}{1+\frac{1}{k}}\right)$$ (I can assure you that this converges). Isn't this number transcendental since the input couldn't be a power of $e$? The denominator of the product is always an integer. It could be proven that: $$\prod^N_{k=1} 1+\frac{1}{k}=N+1$$ Since this is a telescoping product. We could make a limit for $c$: $$c=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\ln \left(\frac{e^{H(N)}}{N+1}\right)$$ Where $H(n)$ is the $n$th harmonic number. $N$ approaches infinity in discrete steps because the product couldn't have a non-integer value on the top bound.

Comment: Isn't every positive number a power of $e$, though?  If $a > 0$ then $a = e^{\ln a}$.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Did you mean "irrational" instead of transcendental?  And are you trying to claim that the limit of a sequence of irrational numbers can't be rational?  That's clearly false, as in $a_n=1-\frac {\sqrt 2}n$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, this kind of argument is not valid. It is true that the logarithms of the partial products

$$H_n - \log (n+1)$$

are transcendental. This follows from the (contrapositive of the) [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), which implies more generally that if $\alpha \neq 1$ is a positive algebraic number then $\log \alpha$ is transcendental. But a limit of transcendental numbers isn't necessarily transcendental or even necessarily irrational; consider e.g. the sequence $\frac{\pi}{n}$ of transcendental numbers which approaches $0$.

In fact your constant $c$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant) $\gamma$ and it's an open problem whether it's irrational.

Comment: The Gelfond-Schneider theorem, in log form, states that when $\alpha,\beta$ are nonzero algebraic numbers and $\beta\neq1$, then for any choice of logarithm we have: $$\frac{\log\alpha}{\log\beta}\text{ is never an algebraic irrational}$$I'm not sure how that fits here

Comment: @FShrike: ah, you're right, we need Lindemann-Weierstrass instead.

Comment: I made a comment about the Lindemann-Weierstrass. It says that the exponential of a nonzero algebraic number is transcendental; so that the logarithm of a nonzero, non-$1$ algebraic number is always transcendental. To apply that here, we'd also need to claim the partial products were algebraic, right? I don't think that's right either (sorry to nitpick but I quite like this kind of number theory, I just want to check my understanding)

Comment: @FShrike: the logarithms of the partial products are the sequence $H_n - \log (n+1)$. Since $H_n$ is rational this number is transcendental iff $\log (n+1)$ is, and then we apply (the contrapositive of) Lindemann-Weierstrass to it. Is it clear now?

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 0):

Well, $$c=\ln \left(\prod^\infty_{k=1}\frac{e^{1/k}}{1+\frac{1}{k}}\right)$$

is nothing but $\ln(e^{\gamma}) = \gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

If this constant is transcendental, is an open problem in Mathematics. Your argument here is invalid.

Comment: Why should this be downvoted?!

Comment: He claims that the argument is invalid but doesn't explain why. It's not an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Well I really don't get the OP's claim "since the input cannot be a power of $e$". Isn't the input an actual power of $e$? $c = \ln(e^{\gamma}) \equiv e^{\ln(e^{\gamma})}$

Comment: @Kurt: the OP is trying to claim intuitively that the logarithms of the *partial* products are transcendental (or maybe irrational, it's a little ambiguous). This is actually true, as I explain in my answer, but it doesn't follow that the limit is transcendental.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh, got it now. Thank you!